# Is Captain America gay?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

First, if you are thinking that this question is a joke or troll, I'd like to welcome you to the 21st century when the mankind is discussing legality of gay marriages.

Now, if you look at the sexuality (I'll keep it clean) of all the Avengers minus Captain America:

- Iron Man: Well, he is a billionaire playboy who can bring hot female journalists to bed with a snap of a finger (*Iron Man* movie). Otherwise, he has a girlfriend who is CEO of a multi-billion dollar company.
- Thor: He has a Nobel prize winning girlfriend who doesn't belong to his species.
- Hulk: Dr. Banner had a girlfriend, but then the gamma accident happened which could turn him into a green monster upon arousal (*The Incredible Hulk* movie). It's still unclear whether he can now have sex or not (after he controlled himself with meditation) and his girlfriend is still with him or not, but he isn't a virgin and nobody knows what happened after *Age of Ultron*. It's possible that Black Widow successfully seduced him after he was found again.
- Black Widow: Although, she is single and she has been sterilized, it's difficult to believe that she is a virgin and she doesn't have sex regularly because she is seen kissing around. And, she was trying to seduce Dr. Banner (*Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie). The point is: She is sexually active.
- Hawkeye: He is married (*Avengers: Age of Ultron* movie).

Now, look at Captain America:

- When Peggy kissed him in *Captain America* movie, it was their first kiss and then he got iced.
- Fast forward to 21st century: Although his age is 80+, he is still young. Yet, he doesn't have a girlfriend and he doesn't show any interest in girls. Even when Black Widow kissed him, he didn't try to drag her to bed.
- Talking about low libido (a medical condition which arises due to stress and other factors), it's impossible because his super soldier serum should keep him healthy in all way. From the functional biology point of view, low libido is actually caused by imbalance of hormones. Stress suppresses rest-and-digest autonomous nervous system and activates fight-or-flight autonomous nervous system (that's why stress, depression etc damage health). In case of Captain America, yes, he got negative emotions after he was defrosted, but his super soldier serum should take care of his biological health. So, one of the other possibilities: He is gay (which has been proved to be a natural condition, not some kind of abnormality).

To prove that he is gay, let's look at his emotional responses: In 21st century, when he met Peggy, he didn't become emotional. But, when he saw Bucky, he became emotional.

I am a straight male and I am creative enough to emulate the situation well. If I had met my first love in such situation, I would have become emotional and it'd actually hurt to know that she is old and I am young. Talking about a dead best friend who is somehow alive and attacking me, my natural response would start with a slang. By no means, Captain America's emotional response looks straight man's response and it looks a gay's response.

Is Captain America really gay? Am I overthinking or producers are really hinting something to throw later? These days it's common in media for awareness. For example, Flash (2014) TV show has a gay police officer.

A more general question: Has sexual orientation of Captain America been disclosed? If he isn't gay, is he straight (there are lots of sexual orientations e.g. Bisexuality)? What about comics?

Comment: Or it could simply be that he's chosen to be celibate.

Comment: You could similarly ask "Why doesn't Captain America poop?" The writers have never felt it was important to establish his sexuality one way or the other, just like it isn't important to establish that he has bodily functions.

Comment: Suggesting that he's gay because he kissed Black Widow but "didn't try to drag her to bed" is ridiculous - it doesn't mean he's gay, it means he's not a sexual predator.

Comment: Also, the suggestion that any woman isn't a virgin because she kisses people is absurd and offensive - welcome to the 21st century, where people kiss before they have sex.  The premise of the question isn't bad, but the way you asked it is totally inappropriate.

Comment: voting to reopen. this isnt a future works, nor is it in any way opinion based.

Comment: In the films he's overtly Christian. That would certainly go a long way to explaining his aversion to pre-marital sex.

Comment: Voting to re-open, but this should be closed as off-topic, since the **premise** of this question is flawed: "*I* think this is what makes him gay, do you think so too?"; which is explicitly [off-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Until it gets revised and improved, I think it's poor quality and not a fit for this site.

Comment: @Mooz You misread. It's "I think this is what makes him gay, does the canon address this?"..

Comment: There is always some gaymance involved when you put a bunch of guys together. Cap and bucky have been in a war together. They were very close friends. Finding out that bucky isnt dead but brainwashed by the enemy would be a really big emotional hit to a soldier buddy and a genuine friend. Take a look at war survivors from our own time man! Most of the suffer from guilt and other kind of emotions about their dead friends. Now imagine that an iraq/afgan vet foud out that their best friend was alive and brainwashed by terrorists!! They would also react violently! Does that make them gay too?

Comment: @Cherubel But, he didn't react violently.

Comment: @SS-3 i didn't meant it literally. No he didn't go all Hulk and smash stuff. He was emotional about it. that was what i meant by violently.

Answer (score 33):

Yes. You're ***seriously*** overthinking things.

To my knowledge, there has never been any direct remarks about Steve Rogers sexuality in the MCU, but his actions overall show no reason to assume he's not heterosexual.

He was just beginning a traditional 1940's-style relationship with Peggy Carter at the time he crashed into the ice. His *very last conversation* with her was discussing a date they would never get to have. By the time he re-awoke, that relationship was obviously past. He goes to visit her in the hospital, showing that he still feels some connection to her, but there's no real chance for relationship there.

In *Captain America: Winter Soldier*, we can clearly see Steve and Sharon Carter flirting, and he asks her out on a date. At the end of the movie, Black Widow even strongly recommends her persue that relationship.

There's also hints of a relationship between himself and Black Widow, such as his remarks in *Age of Ultron* to Banner.

You are attempting to analyze his behavior based on the behavior we might expect from college frat boys in the year 2015. He's from the 1940s; his upbringing would have instilled in him "proper etiquette" for getting involved with a woman, including a slow and *chaste* period of "courting" (which he was clearly doing with Peggy), though not necessarily anything so formal. But he certainly is not the kind of person to grab the nearest single woman and hop into bed with her.

Answer (score 18):

**Is Captain America gay? No.** That doesn't throw out the possibility of him being bi, but he clearly has *some* attraction to women.

### Update:

In Captain America: Civil War

> Captain America kisses Sharon Carter. He then makes a comment that it was long over due.

So, my earlier point that he is classic slow moving guy holds up..

### Original:

Captain America clearly *fancied* Peggy Carter, as he kept a picture of her in his compass.

[image]

He also did not pull back with revulsion when Black Widow drew him for a kiss to evade the SHIELD agents.

[image]

As to why he didn't "drag her to bed." Captain America is not a crazed satyriac like Tony Stark. He is the kind of guy who likes to court a girl and isn't out just for sex, but for a lasting and meaningful relationship.

Captain America also invites Sharon Carter to use his washing machine, which is a kind of 'get to know you' approach, although she declines.

[image]

**From these three events I think we can safely assume that Captain America at least has some attraction to women.**

Comment: Keeping Peggy's photo can be confusion. A psychological issue of gays. Lots of gays start dating girls just to realize they are gay.

Comment: Annnnd well done, you've just shown why it is impossible to prove a negative.

Comment: I don't think the question is a joke, but I do think it's a troll.

Comment: @MajorStackings sure it's a troll, not a question so much as an deliberate opening to make commentary about homosexuality. That isn't what this site is for.

Answer (score 15):

#### Perhaps the Marvel Cinematic Universe doesn't show Captain America being all that interested in women, but considering he is a man out of time, it might be a while before he hits his emotional stride again.

You do have to remember he is a man living in the early 2000's with the mentality and cultural mores of a 1940's soldier. It will take time for him to adjust and become culturally aware enough to successfully date.

As for the comic version of the character, Captain America has had more than a few girlfriends over the years and has been clearly heterosexual despite the fan-fiction to the contrary.

I can name at least three:

- Rachel Leighton AKA Diamondback (a reformed villain) was an interesting girlfriend for Steve Rogers, since she was trying to get him to join the rest of us in the late 20th Century. She was young energetic and ultimately not suited for a straight-laced guy like Steve. I did like her time in his book. She gets extra credit for being the first time Cap going on a date made a cover!
- Bernie Rosenthal: A woman of Jewish heritage, Bernie Rosenthal was renowned as one of the most talented glass blowers in the New York metroplex. Rosenthal once held a long-standing romantic relationship with Steve Rogers. They were, at one time, engaged to be married.
- Sharon Carter: Was the woman most suited to be partnered with Steve Rogers, Sharon Carter was a SHIELD operative who teamed up with Rogers on more than one occasion. They had great chemistry and eventually became lovers. Of any of the women Steve has ever been connected to, Sharon Carter came the closest to be the right woman for him.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

### We don't know if Steve Rogers is really secretly gay or bi-sexual and hiding it or living in denial (see: Bobby Drake), but he has never shown any outward hints of romantic or sexual feelings towards other men.

Additionally, he has had romantic (and presumably sexual) relationships with women in the past.

---

#### In the comics

Before his freeze, [Peggy Carter](http://www.comicvine.com/peggy-carter/4005-35979/) was Steve's girlfriend for a time.

[image: cap and peggy]

Steve Rogers has also had a relationship with [Sharon Carter](http://marvel.com/universe/Carter,_Sharon).

They talked about getting married, and they've even kissed.

[image: They even kiss!]

Additionally, in at least one alternate universe, [he has been married to a woman](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Rogers_%28Earth-3490%29).

He's also dated his neighbor [Bernadette Rosenthal](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bernadette_Rosenthal_%28Earth-616%29), and has also professed his love for her.

[image: cap and bernie]

Not all of his girlfriends were on the side of good, though. He also dated [Diamondback](http://marvel.com/universe/Diamondback_%28Rachel_Leighton%29), a member of the Serpent Society.

[image: cap and diamondback]

---

#### In the Marvel Cinematic Universe

Steve has shown romantic interest in Peggy Carter, and laments his lost chance with her. But it's true that we haven't seen him in any relationship *yet*.

Part of this can be attributed to Steve feeling like a fish out of water and not being able to find someone with enough common ground between them. He explains this in *The Winter Soldier*. Per [the transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier)

> Natasha Romanoff: Was that your first kiss since 1945?
>
> Steve Rogers: That bad, huh?
>
> Natasha Romanoff: I didn't say that.
>
> Steve Rogers: Well, it kind of sounds like that's what you're saying.
>
> Natasha Romanoff: Nobody special, though? [Steve chuckles]
>
> Steve Rogers: Believe it or not, it's kind of hard to find someone with shared life experience.

Additionally, he's also a pretty busy guy. While the scene is played partially for laughs, it's also pretty true. He's working with SHIELD, and constantly out on dangerous missions - not the best situation if he's looking for a serious relationship.

> Natasha Romanoff: You know, if you ask Kristen out, from Statistics, she'll probably say yes.
>
> Steve Rogers: That's why I don't ask.
>
> Natasha Romanoff: Too shy or too scared?
>
> Steve Rogers: Too busy! [Steve jumps out of the jet]

However, Emily Van Camp has said in an interview that [there will be hints of a romance between them in *Civil War*.](http://www.etonline.com/movies/177762_emily_vancamp_teases_captain_america_love_story_and_epic_civil_war_fight_scenes/)

> We get to explore... I can't say we are going to that extent of it, but they are certainly getting to know each other. And they know who each other are.

This was confirmed in the final cut of the movie when the two share a romantic (and passionate) kiss.

Answer (score 7):

So a man who has difficulty interfacing with people because of a century of culture shift and was always rather shy with women not grabbing random women off the street and bending them over the hood of a car must therefore be gay? Cap is also a hardcore boy scout who may well not believe in sex before marriage. He is very old and has nobody to talk to with any kind of shared experiences who isn't nearing a hundred years old.

Given that he is shy romantically, and the entire cultural divide (which they even joke about constantly in the movies with him not getting references), not even getting any kind of slang, I think it is absolutely reasonable to be reticent with regards to sex.

But this should be a good takeaway for real life too: you can't begin to judge someone else's sexuality based on suuuuper outdated stereotypes. And similarly, number of people slept with is not any kind of metric of a person for good or ill, it's just a number.

Comment: But, he also became emotional after seeing Bucky.

Comment: @SS-3: Being emotional after seeing Bucky isn't any sort of "proof" of being gay or even bisexual.  It is possible to care about someone in a non-romantic way, even very strongly - the scenario would work just as well with the emotions of a friend, or a beloved brother, come back from the dead and also brainwashed.  The interaction was unexpected, so shock, guilt, and disbelief may also play a role.  Calling that 'a gay's response' seems overly simplistic.

Comment: Wow, please take this somewhere else and NOT in the comments section to an answer which I thought I had deleted to avoid this exact thing but the site apparently put back up.