# Is Colossus asexual in nature?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016, colossus

During the last fight in *Deadpool* (2016), Colossus covered his face with his hand when Angel Dust's top came down showing her *ahem* "assets".

Why did he cover his face - is he asexual in nature?

Comment: Allowing someone some modesty does not in any way imply that they're asexual.

Comment: @phantom42 I've edited the question to read "prudish" instead of "asexual"; do you agree?

Comment: I suspect the OP really did mean asexual, but this is close enough.

Comment: @SQB No, not really. They're two separate things. Like Mike, I believe it really probably *is* what they were *intending* to ask, but it's not what they asked. Changing intent of the question should be left to OP.

Comment: @phantom42 okay, edit or revert as you see fit. I feel uncomfortable with the question's original wording, though.

Comment: @SQB which is probably why its getting downvoted to hell lol

Comment: Angel Dust's cleavage was showing **to the camera**.  The clear implication of the scene was that he shielded his vision because her entire breast had come out of her outfit, not merely the cleavage.

Comment: @SQB - While it is clear that this is in the same vein as [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay) (i.e. some dubious assumptions about sexuality), nonetheless the author's intent should always be preserved.

Comment: Why would averting your eyes be in any way relevant to asexuality? If anything, asexual people would reasonably be expected to be _less_ likely to avert their eyes than ‘normalsexual’ (is there a word for the opposite of ace?) people.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Hypersexual" is the word you are looking for.

Comment: @Lexible No, not hypersexual. Just anyone who's not asexual (the vast majority falling within the normal range of libido and level of sexual desire).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh! So you simply mean "*sexual*". :) I thought you meant "unusually strong sexuality" or something like that. :)

Comment: @Lexible Yup, basically. ‘Sexual people’ just conjures up slightly different connotations.

Comment: @Lexible I believe that, because of the preexisting connotations of the adjective "sexual", the preferred terms for human sexualities that are not asexual are *allosexual* or *verisexual*, depending on how much one cares about etymology (in terms of composition, the former would be closer to either "heterosexual" or the opposite of "autosexual" rather than not-asexual, but it remains considerably more popular than the latter).

Comment: @Darael Eh... I'll stick with "sexual." :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because Colossus is a proper gentleman, and that's what proper gentlemen do when a woman has a wardrobe malfunction.

His character throughout the entire movie was that of a well-behaved, civilized, mature individual in direct contrast to crass and violent Deadpool. He was also attempting to be a good role model for Negasonic Teenage Warhead. It would have been entirely out of character for him to ogle a woman who found herself topless through no fault of her own.

To directly answer your question, though, no, Colossus is not asexual. In the comics he is in a relationship with Kitty Pryde. They haven't touched on this in the movies yet but there's no indication that his movie character is any different.